# initialize select tag with php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select tag ...

```
<select id="input_O6" type="text" name="select_input">
        <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
        <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
        <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
        <option value="Level 4">Level 4</option>
        <option value="Level 5">Level 5</option>
        <option value="Level 6">Level 6</option>
        <option value="Level 7">Level 7</option>
        <option value="Level 8">Level 8</option>
        </select>
```

the user selects a value and I store the selected value to the sql database.
When I reload the page, I'm retrieving the value selected in my php and I'm trying to set the select tag to this value. 
Other inputs, I simply do it like this...

```
<input id="input_O3" type="number" value=<?php echo $storedValue_O3;?>>
```

Is there a simple way to do this for the select tag?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to check every value in that `select` and check if its same then add a `selected="selected`" to the option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option field has a `selected` attribute. You can set this using php:

```
<select id="input_O6" type="text" name="select_input">
    <option value="Level 1" <?php echo ($selectedval == 1 ? 'selected' : '') ?>>Level 1</option>
    <option value="Level 2" <?php echo ($selectedval == 2 ? 'selected' : '') ?>>Level 2</option>
    <option value="Level 3" <?php echo ($selectedval == 3 ? 'selected' : '') ?>>Level 3</option>
    <option value="Level 4" <?php echo ($selectedval == 4 ? 'selected' : '') ?>>Level 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks... this does just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 1; $i<=8; $i++){

  $selected = ($storedValue_O3 == $i) ? "selected" : null;

  echo "<option value='Level ".$i."' ".$selected.">Level ".$i."</option> ";

}
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code, explain how/why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Get the input variable From `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending upon your form submission method.

Get all the drop down options in an array, loop over them.

And create options.

If you get the selected value, make the particular `option` selected, otherwise, not selected.

This should work.

```
<?php
$select_input = ! empty($_POST['select_input']) ? $_POST['select_input'] : '';
```

//Get the input variable:

```
?>
```

And Do the following changes:

```
<?php
$select_input = ! empty($_POST['select_input']) ? $_POST['select_input'] : '';
$arrInp = array();
$arrInp['Level 1'] = 'Level 1';
$arrInp['Level 2'] = 'Level 2';
$arrInp['Level 3'] = 'Level 3';
$arrInp['Level 4'] = 'Level 4';

$arrInp['Level 5'] = 'Level 5';
$arrInp['Level 6'] = 'Level 6';
$arrInp['Level 7'] = 'Level 7';
$arrInp['Level 8'] = 'Level 8';
?>


<select id="input_O6" type="text" name="select_input">
    <?php
    foreach ($arrInp as $k => $v) {
        $selected = ($select_input == $k) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $k;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $v;?></option>
        <?php
 } 
       ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you have mistyped `$_POST['select_input']` multiple times, plus the OP explained he is getting his values from a SQL query - not a POST/GET request